# Can anyone identify this object?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

[image]  [image]
[image]

It was found on the shore of the Ohio River in Kentucky. It is very hard, like bone, and feels hollow but does not rattle.  It is translucent.  I do not think it is skull of a water fowl even though the blunt end appears beak-like. I cannot figure out if it is plant or animal.  It was found in an area where arrowheads were found.

It appears to be hollow. I do not believe it is a shell since there is no margin or growth lines. It appears to be shriveled or desiccated.

Answer (score 10):

This may be, though not sure, one of the supporting bones of the dorsal spine of the black drum,

> *Pogonias cromis* also known as drum or drummer.
> It is the only species in the genus Pogonias.
> [Reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_drum)

> Freshwater drums are native to **Ohio**, preferring habitats of deeper pools of rivers and in Lake Erie with clear water and clean bottoms. They spawn from April to late summer.
> [Reference](https://ohiohistorycentral.org/w/Freshwater_Drum)

[image]

> Pogonias courbina is distinguished by the following characters: the occurrence of character-
> istic thickening of the dorsal spines VII to XI in all specimens larger than 250 mm SL; all pter-
> ygiophores in the dorsal-fin laminar, thin; anal-fin pterygiophores slender excluded those of
> spines; lateral projections of gas bladder with few finger-like projections; genetic distance
> between both species 1%

[image]

An important site that helped me to identify this-

https://txmarspecies.tamug.edu/otherdetails.cfm?scinameID=black%20drum%20pterygiophore

Comment: Thank you.  Additional sources say it is a Tilly bone, perhaps from a large catfish.  A Tilly bone is caused by hyperostosis, or excessive bone growth and is found in many fish.

Comment: @Kevin Oravec you may accept the answer if you are satisfied, for the future references.